# Identity problem while I'm trying to login with ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API project and I'm using the v3.1.10 packages for aspnetcore.tools, SQL Server, jwtbearer, and I have installed the v2.2.0 of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity`.

I'm getting this error message at postman output line:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[API.Authentication.ApplicationUser]' while attempting to activate 'API.Controllers.AuthenticationController'.

My startup file is :

```cs
services.AddControllers();
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(option => option.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnStr")));
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser,IdentityRole>()         
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

services.AddAuthentication(option =>
{
    option.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    option.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    option.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.SaveToken = true;
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidAudience = Configuration["JWT:ValidAudience"],
        ValidIssuer = Configuration["JWT:ValidIssuer"],
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["JWT:Secret"]))
    };
});
```

and my controller is :

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class AuthenticationController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private readonly RoleManager<ApplicationUser> _roleManager;
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public AuthenticationController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, RoleManager<ApplicationUser> roleManager,IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _roleManager = roleManager;
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Register")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Register([FromBody] RegisterModel model)
    {
        var userExist = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.UserName);
        if (userExist !=null)
        {
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, new Response {Status="Error",Massage="User Already Exist" });
        }
        ApplicationUser user = new ApplicationUser()
        {
            Email = model.Email,
            SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            UserName = model.UserName
        };
        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, new Response { Status = "Error", Massage = "User creation failed" });
        }
        return Ok(new Response { Status="Success" , Massage = "Successfuly created"});
    }
```

i couldn't find the what's wrong with this code.

Comment: `RoleManager<IdentityRole>` ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.rolemanager-1?view=aspnetcore-5.0)). Your `TRole` is wrong